# A more beautiful output of \under- and \overbrace

Tags: spacing, equations, overbrace

Expert,

is there any way to get the output of my equation more beautiful e.g. asking LaTeX to igrnore the horizontal space that \underbrace and \overbrace reserve for themselves?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(300,20)
\put(50,10){\vector(2,-3){20}}
\put(50,10){\vector(2,-1){60}}
\put(-10,15){these guys \textbf{here} must be eliminated. The next one \textbf{here} too, of course.}
\put(230,10){\vector(-2,-3){20}}
\end{picture}
\[ \{ \underbrace{x \in \mathbb{Z}}_{\text{Menge aller $x$ aus $\mathbb{Z}$}} \overbrace{|}^{\text{mit der Eigenschaft}} -1 \le x \le 2 \} \]
\\[1cm]
And I want to get it like this:
\[ \{x \in \mathbb{Z} \ | \ -1 \le x \le 2 \}, \]
where the \verb|\overbrace| doesn't wait till the \verb|\underbrace| is going to have the work done.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would like to suggest you load the `mathtools` package and use its `\mathclap` macro to "smash" the *widths* of the explanatory strings "`\text{Menge aller $x$ aus $\mathbb{Z}$}`" and "`\text{mit der Eigenschaft}`". I would use an `\overset` directive instead of `\overbrace` to typeset the (stacked) material above the vertical bar. (An overbrace is just too wide relative to the vertical bar.)

With this approach, the explanatory strings will be typeset in `\scriptstyle`, i.e., with a font that's 30% smaller than the main math font style (which is `\textstyle`).

Separately, do note that the vertical bar should be of type `mathrel`. If it's written as `\vert` or as `|`,  it should be surrounded by thickspaces (`\;`). Or, more simply, just write `\mid`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathclap macro
\usepackage{amsfonts}  % for \mathbb macro
\begin{document}

\[ \{\,
\underbrace{x \in \mathbb{Z}}_{%
   \mathclap{\text{Menge aller $x$ aus $\mathbb{Z}$}}} 
\overset{\mathclap{\substack{%
   \text{mit der Eigenschaft}\\ \downarrow}}}{\mid}
-1 \le x \le 2 % wrap the minus symbol in braces so that it acts as a unary operator
\,\} \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\overset{...}{\mid}` becomes a Rel atom just like `\mid`. No need for tricks with minus one.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for this. I'll change the code.

Comment: @ Mico, thank you for your answer! Your variant looks much better than the output I had! 
It seems like the number of manuals  I should read grows exponentially according to the things a want to implement... :) 

Is `\mathclap` the only command that you used from the `mathtools` package? I have never heard about `\mid` and `\overset` before. Where can I get information about the correct usage of them?
Thank you again!

Comment: @Kirill -  Glad you found my answer useful. :-) About the macros: `\mid` is defined in both PlainTeX and LaTeX;`\overset`, `\substack` and `\text` are defined in the [amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package, which is loaded automatically by the `mathtools` package; and `\mathclap` is defined in the [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with `mathtools` (an extension of `amsmath`) and `stackengine`. For short underbraces, `\underbracket` looks nicer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, stackengine}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\setstackEOL{\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(300,20)
\put(50,10){\vector(2,-3){20}}
\put(50,10){\vector(2,-1){60}}
\put(-10,15){these guys \textbf{here} must be eliminated. The next one \textbf{here} too, of course.}
\put(230,10){\vector(-2,-3){20}}
\end{picture}
\[ \bigl\{ \underbracket[0.5pt]{x \in \mathbb{Z}}_{\clap{\footnotesize Menge aller $x$ aus $\mathbb{Z}$}} \stackrel{\Shortstack {\clap{\footnotesize mit der Eigenschaft}\\$\downarrow $}}{\mid} -1 \le x \le 2\bigr\} \]
\\[1cm]
And I want to get it like this:
\[ \{x \in \mathbb{Z} \ | \ -1 \le x \le 2 \}, \]
where the \verb|\overbrace| doesn't wait till the \verb|\underbrace| is going to have the work done.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you enlarge the sizes of the outer curly braces, shouldn't you also enlarge the size of the vertical bar, i.e., write `\bigm|` instead of `\mid`?

Comment: @Bernard, I get ! `LaTeX Error: File `listofitems.sty' not found.` when I try to load the `stackengine`. Should it be installed in a different way than `\usepackage`? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: This means you don't have the `listofitems` package installed. It is required by `stackengine`. Which distribution do you have?

Comment: This was a MikTeX distribution in a basic version. Should I add `\listofitmes` to the package list? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, with MiKTeX Package Manager (admin). You made me discover it was required!

Comment: "Houston, we've had a problem..." I get an error `Windows Api 87 error` trying to start a MiKTeX (admin) PM. And, I cannot find `listofitems` with the usual MiKTeX package manager.

Comment: Looks like the compiler is waiting for an answer. You can't launch both the compiler and M.P.M.  Also, synchronize the repository.